# powershell replace string with special character does NOT work

Tags: powershell

```
$strText = '<httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="*" />
    other content ....
        </httpHandlers>

$Pattern = '<remove verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="*" />'
$New ='<remove verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="*" NEW CONTENT ADDED />'
$strReplace = [regex]::replace($strText, $pattern, $New)`
```

seems not work

Comment: You may want to more clearly explain what you are hoping to see.

Comment: Using regular expressions to modify XML is a bad idea. Powershell already provides good functionality to parse, modify and save an XML document.

Answer (score 1):

```
$strText = '<httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="*" />
    other content ....
        </httpHandlers>'

$Pattern = [regex]::escape('<remove verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="*" />')
$New ='<remove verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="*" NEW CONTENT ADDED />'
$strReplace = [regex]::replace($strText, $pattern, $New)
$strReplace
```

1. Your string `$strText` was missing a quote
2. Your pattern contains special characters. Used the static method [`[regex]::escape`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) to account for that.
3. Not really an issue but you had a trailing backtick that seemed out of place.